# Отбор ника telegram из строки php

Tags: php

Всем привет. Есть такая ситуация, в строке, может быть ник telegram. Например:
`$str = "Текст текст текст. @nicktelegram"` или `$str = "Текст текст текст. nicktelegram"` и т д.
Как можно программно через PHP вычислить что это ник telegram?

Comment: Видимо написать регулярное выражение которое будет парсить строку на наличие в ней `nicknametelegram`

Comment: @phpBear очевидно, nicknametelegram это не константа

Comment: Если со случаем `@nickname` все довольно просто, но относительное второго варианта не ясно как вы хотите выделить ник. последнее слово из текста?

Comment: Если сдесь используется только латиница, то воспользуйся регулярными выражениями. Информация по регулярным выражения: http://archive-ipq-co.narod.ru/l1/regexp.html

Comment: @teran то, что это не константа, а пример вполне понятно. я озвучил общее решение - а какие он вобьет в `preg_match` шаблоны поиска - уже ему виднее.

Answer (score 0):

В первом случае как то так

```
$string = 'test @string test';
preg_match('/(@\w*)/ui',$string,$matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Результат: @string

Во втором случае так или иначе нужно как-то отделить никнейм от текста. Символами, например. Затем по тому же сценарию с регулярным выражением

Comment: в вопросе "...через PHP вычислить что это ник telegram..." регуляркой можно вытянуть нужные части по маске, только это не гарантирует что это ник, пример @qwerty123456rertertertertert  - не гарантирует что это ник из телеги, тут нужно по API или еще как в самом telegram дополнительно проверять. А если автор хочет еще и вытаскивать из $str = "Текст текст текст. nicktelegram" , то придется все слова на латинице проверть через телегу -  это как-то выглядит утопично.